# Convert HTML5 application into standalone Android App

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have a dynamic HTML document that contains external resources (images, css and scripts are coded inside of document). This HTML5 application is working fine within an internet browser. Is it possible to convert this HTML5 application into a standalone Android application?

Please give me step by step instructions this is my first HTML app.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Phonegap (http://phonegap.com). You simply upload your web app to their service, and you can download the Android APK.

Now, although you can simply do the above and end there, Phonegap has unique sets of APIs that will allow you do a lot of native mobile functions that a typical web app does not have access to. This includes Geolocation, Accelerometer Camera, Contacts, Database, File system, and more, all through Javascript.

Few things to keep in mind while creating a HTML app for the first time:

- Make sure your website is responsive. This way, any mobile device can view the page and users wont have to zoom in to an app created for the desktop.
- Clicking tends to be laggy due to the 300ms delay on a mobile browser, so use fastclick.js (https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to remove that and make your app quicker.

In addition, if you want to create an iOS or Windows phone app along with your Android App, Ph has the option to that too.

Comment: Can anyone on here show me how to do just that with team viewer and then we can workout some sort of compensation

Comment: Sure. How can I contact you?

Comment: Just tried the web based one at https://build.phonegap.com/. Still completely functional.

Answer (score 2):

You could use phonegap to convert your HTML5 application to a native android application
http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to develop a Google Chrome Packaged app. The new API will allow developers to create apps that run as a Chrome app, but also as a "native" app in both Android & iOS platforms.

Google provides an excellent documentation and tutorials. You can find more information here: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html

Comment: PhoneGap and Cordova are most likely to suit to the PO's need (and should be marked as the anser, @user2388119 !), but this is a valuable answer as well, as it offers people a solution they (maybe) wouldn't think of otherwise.